# List of atomic shared pointers

Tags: c++, thread-safety, atomic, c++20

I need a thread-safe list of shared pointers and I saw that in c++20 they added template specializations for the atomic shared _ptr. (`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Delegate>>`).

I was thus wondering do I need to implement my own doubly-linked list or this is what I need `std::list<std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Delegate>>>` for my thread-safe list?

Comment: What operations need to be "thread-safe" and in which way?

Comment: @NicolBolas Push_back, push_front, insert, size regular operation on a container. I figured since a list is 2 pointers if they are atomic they should be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::list<std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Delegate>>>` is a list of atomic pointers.  This means the pointers have some thread safety guarantees.

It is not an atomic list, nor does the list structure have any extra thread safety compared with the same structure with no `std::atomic`.

So for example if you have two threads which hold references to elements in the list, it is safe for one of them to modify the pointer and the other one to read it (the reader will see either the old or the new value).

But if you modify the list (push, pop, clear, etc) in one thread while reading or modifying it in another thread, that's undefined behavior.  For that you'd probably want to use a different, thread-safe container, or protect the `std::list` with a `std::mutex`.

Comment: Yes I realized it, when I tried to use it. Plus it doesn't even compile whenI call push_back because std::atomic<std::shared_ptr> is missing operations that are required by std::list.